# SQL Server database design, which one is better design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL Server and am confused as to whether I should put `City`, `State` and `Country` in one table or should I create 3 different tables with foreign keys?

[image][image]

Please suggest which one is best for performance and future modifications etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is better, as rule of thumb, always say if I need to rename a 'country' name how many records should be updated, if your answer is 1 then your design is good. (In first design the number of records that should be updated is as much as number of cities in that contry)

Answer (score 1):

The second, normalized one, is better, of course.

But you don't need CountryId in City table, if city is dependant on state and only indirectly on country.

Answer (score 1):

Your second database design is hands down better one as it satisfies [NORMALIZATION](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878)